# Heroku build fails always - Says no module named six

Tags: python, heroku, six

```
    Counting objects: 1260, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1208/1208), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1260/1260), 6.24 MiB | 184.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1260 (delta 109), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.13
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting appdirs==1.4.3 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting click==6.7 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==0.12.2 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==0.24 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.9.6 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting packaging==16.8 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting pyparsing==2.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
remote:        Collecting six==1.10.0 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==0.12.2 (from -r /tmp/build_05ed4039dfcb7243b9f260b604feea9c/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: appdirs, click, itsdangerous, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Flask, gunicorn, pyparsing, six, packaging
remote:          Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: finished with status 'error'
remote:            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-H6YgNg/itsdangerous/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VAC6vv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
remote:            running install
remote:            running build
remote:            running build_py
remote:            creating build
remote:            creating build/lib
remote:            copying itsdangerous.py -> build/lib
remote:            running install_lib
remote:            copying build/lib/itsdangerous.py -> /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
remote:            byte-compiling /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py to itsdangerous.pyc
remote:            running install_egg_info
remote:            running egg_info
remote:            writing itsdangerous.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote:            writing top-level names to itsdangerous.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote:            writing dependency_links to itsdangerous.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote:            reading manifest file 'itsdangerous.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:            reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
remote:            writing manifest file 'itsdangerous.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:            Copying itsdangerous.egg-info to /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous-0.24-py2.7.egg-info
remote:            running install_scripts
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-H6YgNg/itsdangerous/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
remote:                'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
remote:                dist.run_commands()
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
remote:                self.run_command(cmd)
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
remote:                cmd_obj.run()
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
remote:                return orig.install.run(self)
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 575, in run
remote:                self.run_command(cmd_name)
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
remote:                self.distribution.run_command(command)
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
remote:                cmd_obj.run()
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 17, in run
remote:                import setuptools.command.easy_install as ei
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 49, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.py27compat import rmtree_safe
remote:              File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/py27compat.py", line 7, in <module>
remote:                import six
remote:            ImportError: No module named six
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-H6YgNg/itsdangerous/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VAC6vv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-H6YgNg/itsdangerous/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to searchword.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/searchword.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/searchword.git'
```

I don't know what is happening. Few days ago, I was able to deploy apps on heroku with no such error. I am running on virtual environment. I activated it before pushing to heroku master. I even checked which pip I am referring to but all in vain. I have installed module 'six' on my local machine and on virtual environment even. Still always it says No module named six and fails my deploy. Please help!! Its frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Because it is google translation, I'm sorry if it turned funny.
I was addicted in exactly the same situation.
I do not know why it went well, but I replaced it to describe
"six == 1.10.0" at the beginning of "requirements.txt" and deployed it.
by the way, but my version of python is 3.6・・・

Comment: Yes. Solution is installing six before anything else. Reason is stated in @AshishRanjan comment

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue currently with the latest release of setuptools (36.0.0). You can track the issue here - https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1042

Comment: I installed six first, but nothing happened. By the way the problem is solved now. I updated my setuptools using pip and after that heroku is showing no errors.

Comment: The order in which packages appear in `requirements.txt` file, doesn't ensure that packages will actually be installed in the same order by `pip`. Please refer this - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3480

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the module needing six from the reqirements.txt. Then push to heroku and the build was succesful. Next I added the package which needed six and it worked.